# Missing columns of the joined table in ResultSet (SQLITE)

Tags: java, sql, sqlite

I don`t get it. I created a query where made some joins of two tables in SQLite. In my SQLite Browser there is all ok and the columns are displayed correctly. But when I call executeQuery, I always get the error:

[SQLITE_ERROR] SQL error or missing database (no such column: td.value)

Here is my statement:

```
private static final String QUERY_ENDUSES = "SELECT td.Value Value, reportn.Value ReportName, fs.Value ReportForString, tn.Value TableName, rn.Value RowName, cn.Value ColumnName, u.Value Units, RowId "
        + "FROM TabularData td"
        + "INNER JOIN Strings reportn ON reportn.StringIndex=td.ReportNameIndex "
        + "INNER JOIN Strings fs ON fs.StringIndex=td.ReportForStringIndex "
        + "INNER JOIN Strings tn ON tn.StringIndex=td.TableNameIndex "
        + "INNER JOIN Strings rn ON rn.StringIndex=td.RowNameIndex "
        + "INNER JOIN Strings cn ON cn.StringIndex=td.ColumnNameIndex "
        + "INNER JOIN Strings u ON u.StringIndex=td.UnitsIndex WHERE report n.StringTypeIndex=1 AND fs.StringTypeIndex=2 AND tn.StringTypeIndex=3 AND rn.StringTypeIndex=4 AND cn.StringTypeIndex=5 AND u.StringTypeIndex=6 "
        + "AND td.ReportNameIndex = 1 AND tn.StringIndex = 59;";
```

If I substitute the statement through `Select td.value from TabularData td` , then all is OK!

Can anybody help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're missing a space between `td` in the `FROM` clause, and the first `INNER`.

Comment: I cant believe it. You`re absolutely right. Shame on me. I looked at it for hours just to make sure there are spaces everywhere. I am really grateful and so sorry for making this thread.